# How to Access codemirror text area value in Angular2 Component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, codemirror

I am trying to link codemirror with Angular 2 (TypeScript) .
Right now ,I am able to display CodeEditor using a codearea custom directive ,which dynamically loads a script file and Formats the text area .

I am not able to get the value ,the user types in the text area ,I have tried NgModel,value etc ,I think codemirror is removing the textarea and re inserting it again ,that might cause an error .

I have tried to use onchange and keyup event handlers ,but they are being repeatedly called when anything is entered in the text area .So that isnt usefull.

Here is the Code of code-Area Component :

```
import {Component, AfterViewChecked,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'code-area',
    template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="ic_code">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="ic_code" id='problem2' name='problem2' rows='10' cols='80'>

    </textarea>
    <div>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="ic_code" id='problem1' name='problem2' rows='10' cols='80'>
    int main(){

    }
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <button (click)="submit_clicked()">Submit</button>
    <input [(ngModel)]="ic_code">
    `
})
export class CodeArea implements AfterViewInit,AfterViewChecked{
    public ic_code;
    public ic_code2;
    public ic_codediv;
    constructor(){
        this.ic_code = "";
        System.import('app/applycodemirror')
            .then(refToLoadedScript => {
                applycodestyle();
            });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log("AFter view init called in CodeArea");
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked(){

    }
    onChange(){
        //This is being repeatedly called
    }
    submit_clicked() {
        //I need the code here ,when user clicks on submit
    }
    onKey(event: any) {
        console.log(event.target.value+' ');
    }

}
```

Here is the external js file

```
function applycodestyle(){
      if(document.getElementById("problem1") != null){
        console.log("Problem 1 present");
        var cEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("problem1"), {
          lineNumbers: true,
          matchBrackets: true,
          mode: "text/x-csrc",
        });
      }else{
        console.log("Problem 1 null");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it a little bit differently but maybe it will help you.
Basiaclly in ngAfterViewInit I create code mirror instance using elementRef:

```
this.cm = CodeMirror(this.elementRef.nativeElement, options);
```

then in the onChange event:

```
this.cm.on('change', (editor: CodeMirror.Editor) => {
  editor.getDoc().getValue();
});
```

If you don't want to use onChange, you can always get the value from code mirror instance, eg.

```
cmInstance.getEditor().getDoc().getValue()
```

Comment: Hey kit ,Can you post a small code sample on plunker ,explaining how did you set elementref ,and can you explain the second code snippet you used ?

Comment: a plunker would be to much time consuming, sorry.
[elementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html) is a service from angular that enables you to get the DOM of component by it's nativeElement property. nativeElement is just a DOM element with all it's goodies. use eg. querySelector method to get DOM element on which you want trigger CodeMirror.

about sec code snipper. code mirror instance has a event listener. you activate it with on(). there you have access to editor from which you can take doc and value.

Comment: Are you importing CodeMirror  , I mean Dosent Typescript throw any error as CodeMirror wouldnt be available .

Comment: you have typings for codemirror. I don't know what are you using typings or tsd so respectivelly typings install codemirror --save-dev --ambient or tsd install codemirror --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng2-codemirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror)

**Install**

`npm install ng2-codemirror --save`

**Setup**

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    var data = {
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Template/js/kpxl/app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':
                'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            //Add these code mirror packages
            'ng2-codemirror': 'npm:ng2-codemirror',
            'codemirror': 'npm:codemirror',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            codemirror: {
                main: 'lib/codemirror.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    };
    data.packages['ng2-codemirror'] = { main: 'lib/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    System.config(data);
})(this);
```

**Use Sample**

Include CodeMirror css files in your page

```
<link href="/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/node_modules/codemirror/theme/ambiance.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Include `CodemirrorModule` in your main module :

```
import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';

@NgModule({
  // ... 
  imports:      [
    CodemirrorModule
  ],
  // ... 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Use in your any `Component`.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample',
  template: `
    <codemirror [(ngModel)]="code"
      [config]="{...}"
      (focus)="onFocus()"
      (blur)="onBlur()">
    </codemirror>
  `
})
export class Sample{
  constructor(){
    this.code = `// Some code...`;
  }
}
```