# is there any alternative for ui-ace in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am working on angular2 and want to display my JSON data in editor.

in angularjs, ui-ace provided me this functionality by doing :

```
<textarea  ui-ace="{
    useWrapMode : true,
    showGutter: true,
    theme:'twilight',
    mode: 'json',
    firstLineNumber: 1,
    onLoad: aceLoaded('jsonEditor'),
    onChange: aceChanged                    
    }" ng-model="jsondata">
```

Now I want to use same functionality in angular2.
any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsondata is a JSON? or it has been converted to a string?

I know that you can add a third parameter to JSON.stringify in order to make friendly the JSON when it is "stringified". For example:

```
$scope.jsondata = JSON.stringify(code, null, '\t');
```

And the string will be formated as if it was a JSON displayed in the browser console. I have used it with Codemirror.

So another alternative to ace-ui could be [Codemirror for Angular](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror) or [Codemirror](https://codemirror.net/), I have used it multiple times and I recommend it.

Interesting link here [about Codemirror + Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130266/how-to-access-codemirror-text-area-value-in-angular2-component)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the npm package `ng2-ace` helps you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace